# How to execute a C++ code with a python code embedded on a system without python installed

Tags: python, c++, exe

I'm trying to create a simple game using C++ with Python embedding. The python code is embedded in my C++ code. I used Python/C API for this. 
There are 2 goals that I would like to achieve:

1) Application should be able to run on a computer that does not have Python installed.

2) Application should be an one standalone executable file(.exe)

For example, the following simple code only works if the system has python already installed on it:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char pySearchPath[] = "Python27"; 
Py_SetPythonHome(pySearchPath); 

Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("print 'Hello World'");
PyRun_SimpleString("for i in range(5):\n"
    "\tprint i,\n");
Py_Finalize();
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Python needs to be installed on the computer or these files should be in the executable's directory:

```
        python27.dll
        Python27\
            DLLs\ (contents of DLLs folder)
            Lib\ (contents of Lib folder)
```

**Question**: How can I include/add/bind these files within my `.exe` so that my application can execute on a system which has no python installed? I would like to have a standalone executable. Is it possible? If yes then please provide some hints about how to accomplish this? I already invested much of time searching in internet but unfortunately I didn't find any thing useful.

Probably, there is an other possibility to solve this problem, however I am not sure. For example could the following method work?

> Python-Code  ----transforming---->  bytecode  ----->  native code  ------->  import in programm

**UPD**: With Cython I generate .pyd file (.dll). How can I generate .h file from its or call some functions in my app(if it is possible, of course)?

Thank you.

Comment: can you not use py2exe http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ?

Comment: As I know, py2exe  transform "clean" .py(!) into .exe. Or how it possible with py2exe?

Comment: It's perfectly possible to include DLLs within py2exe output file, that's what e.g Dropbox client does.

Comment: I think, you did not understood me, or I doesn't undertand you. My main app on C++, and Python scripts only embedded. So, I can't transform .cpp within py2exe. May be I wrong.

Comment: @Dmitry_Mahrachev Don't add new questions to this question. It is better to create a new question and post it. Then you can link these two questions. :)

Comment: You can statically link to Python (to eliminate the DLL dependency), pack the Python code in a zip archive inside your executable, and use the Python zip loader (with your executable in `sys.path`) to load the rest of the standard library. (This is more-or-less the trick that `py2exe` uses).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can embed python in C++.
Google provided me two links that I think can be useful for you. I am not sure if you already knew these links as you didn't mention in your question about your research.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I This link has two part tutorial on this topic.

http://realmike.org/blog/2012/07/05/supercharging-c-code-with-embedded-python/ This link is also discussing the same topic.

*It is basically avoided to paste off site links in the answer. But unfortunately the answer to your question is too long that I am forced to provide the links here. Sorry for that. Just to be safe you should download the whole tutorial from these links, so that you don't regret in future if the tutorials become offline!*

Comment: Thank you. But I saw that(and many others) tutorials. And my question not "CAN I embed...", but "HOW can I launch app without installing Python".

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to do so. If some app needs python then it has to be installed on the system. I can be wrong too. However if you unfortunately don't find any solution then you can simply display a banner when your app starts stating that python is needed to use this app. Then the user will install python him/her self. Many known games do so too. For eg: If a game needs direct-x or .net they simply display a banner and ask the user to install it or to skip it. Yes, this is annoying but currently I have no solution for you. :(

Comment: My game very simple. May be you know, can I(and how) through bytecode from python generete C++ code? Banner - good, but it's my university job and my lecturer will not be happy about it, because my topic is contacting of two languages itself =(

Comment: Sorry, I am getting bit confused. To clarify, finally you have a C++ code that has some python code in it. Now all you want is to run this code on a system that has no python installed on it? This is what you want? Is this correct?

Comment: @Dmitry_Mahrachev I edited your question and made it clear. In the mean time I hope someone could answer it or provide some hint. If you think my edit was not accurate or missed something, then please feel free to edit your question and add what you think that I may have missed or forgotten by mistake. I shall look for a solution too and when I get something I'll be back. All the best!