# Embed and extend Python in c++ without users installing Python

Tags: python, c++, dll

I'm trying to embed Python in my C++ program so users can run their Python scripts (with my python extensions) at runtime, but this requires them to have Python installed and have python27.dll at runtime.

How can I do this without forcing them to install Python2.7?

Alternatively, where does python27.dll look to load Python at runtime? Can I supply the python libraries in my installed directory and have my local copy of python27.dll use them instead of looking for a system-wide installation (which is usually in C:\Python27)

As another option, can I have an entire Python system statically linked to my dll?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477783/how-to-execute-a-c-code-with-a-python-code-embedded-on-a-system-without-python) may be helpful; So may [this](https://www.myoddweb.com/2016/02/27/embed-python-in-your-c-application-without-python-installed-on-guest-machine/).

Comment: @ArnavBorborah regarding the 2nd link, is there a similar embedded version for python2.7? i can't seem to see it on its download page.

Comment: Hmm, there doesn't seem to be one. I went through the releases back to ~3.1, and then the file stops appearing. This appears to be a problem...

Comment: *3.5, not 3.1. It was introduced in 3.5